# I am getting this error. what this issue?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MyHomePage(dirty, state: _MyHomePageState#3fc9e):
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length

Comment: your return value is null.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the length getter on a null value, which you treat as a List in _MyHomePageState.

Comment: Yes solve this issues thank you but I face one another issue. i did not get data from firestore. if possible give me suggestion.

Comment: Make sure that you connected to the Firebase and Firestore properly, check the error that was thrown by Firestore, make sure that you have access to the Firestore to read data. These are my suggestions to find the reason why you don't get the data. :)  
Please check my answer, so others who have the same problem will know that this was the solution in your case.